# Improving on 'if/else' strcmp() ladder to determine a useable value

Tags: c, hash, ordinals

```
//...
if( strcmp( str, "January" ) == 0 )
    month = 1;
else if( strcmp( str, "February") == 0 )
    month = 2;
//...
```

Q: Is there any more efficient way of determining that, for instance, "April" is the fourth month of the year? Repeated calls to `strcmp()` must be terribly inefficient, and `if/else` ladders tedious to code. Sometimes it's "March" and sometimes it's abbreviated as "MAR"... There must be a better way...

Putting the known strings in a sorted array of structs would allow, at least, binary searching, but still involves a lot of guesswork from the code.

Comment: Look up `gperf` to generate a perfect hash of the keys ahead of time.

Comment: It might be worthwhile to construct a *trie* and use that to do quick lookups:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie

Comment: Sure.  You can put the month/numbers in a table in month alpha order and use binary search.  But that's just the simplest way. Lookup in a static set has been very well studied.  Some fancier options are a perfect hash function (try searching for the Gnu tool `gperf`), an [optimal binary search tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimal_binary_search_tree), or a trie. But don't be too quick to optimize.  For only 12 elements the difference between the if chain and these "more efficient" ways is unlikely to make a real difference. Simplicity has its own value.

Comment: @Shawn Thanks for the pointer. `gperf` looks interesting, but larger than the quick (and specific) hashing functions discovered and posted in the answer below. Posted this at the suggestion that it might be useful to someone, somewhere, sometime. Cheers!...

Comment: A good compromise between efficiency and readability is usually to toss all constant string literals into a sorted table, then binary search through it. In this specific case there's just 12 strings to compare with, so (depending on system) it's quite likely that a brute force for loop calling strcmp is actually the most efficient.

Comment: If your binary search "involves a lot of guesswork from the code," you're doing something wrong. In fact, if any code you're writing requires guesswork, you probably should be doing something else.

Comment: @JimMischel Clever, and correct, but wrong. The code can be fine while the iterating evaluation is a flavour of the **guessing** game, "High Low"... Cheers...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a [Can I answer my own question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) answer. Other answers are welcomed.

---

There are several ways of translating an arbitrary string from a finite set of strings into a concise, useable form.
Most of these involve an iterative (or a sub-optimal linear) search involving repeated comparisons (that may need to account for case sensitivity.)

A response to my response to a recent question suggested "sharing" an (admittedly arcane) hashing function that,
with awareness of false positives, return the month ordinal (1-12)
when passed a string containing the name of a month (English) in 7-bit ASCII.
The function performs primitive operations on the 2nd & 3rd character
and out-pops the function's hash value of the string.
Note, "January", "jan" and "JAN" all return the value 1.
Likewise "feb", "FEBRUARY" and "Feb" would return the value 2.

```
static int monthOrd( char cp[] ) {
    return "DIE@CB@LJF@HAG@K"[ cp[1]/4&7 ^ cp[2]*2 &0xF ] &0xF;
}
```

The operations shown were uncovered through a "brute force" permutation of a number of primitive operations
seeking a combination that would return 12 different values between 0x0 and 0xF (4 bits).
The reader is encouraged to take apart each step of the mangling of the bits of the two ASCII characters.
This result was not "invented", but was "discovered".

After the bits of two characters have been mangled,
the value is used as an index into a string (aka "a cheap LUT") whose 12 letters A-L are positioned so that
"?an" (January) will mangle to an index for the letter 'A'.
Masking the low 4 bits of that letter yields the value 1 as the ordinal for the string "JANUARY"...
1 will be the return value when the function is passed variations of the string "Jan".

NB: Using this function allows the caller to check that the string is indeed "JAN", "jan", "January" as suits the application.
The caller need not try to match any of the names of the other 11 months.
This function WILL return the false positive value 1 for the string "Random",
so the caller need only validate against a single month's name (length and case appropriate to the application.)

---

Bonus round:

```
static int wkdayOrd( char cp[] ) {
    return "65013427"[*cp/2 + ~cp[1] & 0x7] & 0x7;
}
```

An equivalent function that converts "Sun(day)" (case insensitive) to 1, "MON" to 2, "tue" to 3, etc...

Again, the caller must confirm the string against only ONE day's name to avoid "false positives".

---

While we're here, the following is an equivalent function for the "number names" from "zero" to "ten", again, case insensitive.
(Number names are not abbreviated like month names or weekday names.)

```
static int numberOrd( char cp[] ) {
    return "@~IBAH~FCGE~~DJ~"[ ( cp[0] ^ cp[1]/2 + cp[2]*4 ) & 0xF ] & 0xF;
}
```

---

**EDIT**
To counter the nay-sayers, here's another one:

```
static int ZodiacOrd( char cp[] ) {
    return "BJGA@@HIECK@@DLF"[(cp[0]/2 ^ (cp[1]/2&1) + cp[2]*2) & 0xF] & 0xF;
}
```

Pass it the name (case ambivalent) of one of the twelve Zodiac signs, and it will return the ordinal of that star sign ("Aries" = 1, ...) Again, like **any** hashing function, there will be collisions with other strings. The caller need only subsequently check against a single known string; not twelve.

---

**Update:**
Drawn back to this for a recent task, an improvement to the month ordinal conversion revealed itself. The code above uses 16(+1) bytes for its LUT. The code below halves that amount. For posterity, the scheme is explained, with examples provided.

**NB:** Above returns `1-12` for valid a month name (or false positive) and `0` for other hash values in the range `0-15`. Below returns `0-11` for valid month names (conforming to `struct tm` convention) and `12` for each of the four other hashes in the range `0-15`. False positives don't magically go away.

```
/*
'#' denotes hashing the ASCII values of 2nd & 3rd letters

Apr: (p#r) =>  0   /want    3 = 0011 -> 0x3
Sep: (e#p) =>  1   /want    8 = 1000 -> 0x8
May: (a#y) =>  2   /want    4 = 0100 -> 0x4
---: (-#-) =>  3   /dont care = 1100 -> 0xc // 12 out of range
Mar: (a#r) =>  4   /want    2 = 0010 -> 0x2
Feb: (e#b) =>  5   /want    1 = 0001 -> 0x1
---: (-#-) =>  6   /dont care = 1100 -> 0xc // 12 out of range
Dec: (e#c) =>  7   /want   11 = 1011 -> 0xB
Oct: (c#t) =>  8   /want    9 = 1001 -> 0x9
Jun: (u#n) =>  9   /want    5 = 0101 -> 0x5
---: (-#-) => 10   /dont care = 1100 -> 0xc // 12 out of range
Aug: (u#g) => 11   /want    7 = 0111 -> 0x7
Jan: (a#n) => 12   /want    0 = 0000 -> 0x0
Jul: (u#l) => 13   /want    6 = 0110 -> 0x6
---: (-#-) => 14   /dont care = 1100 -> 0xc // 12 out of range
Nov: (o#v) => 15   /want   10 = 1010 -> 0xA

==>> uint64_t LUT = 0xAc607c59Bc12c483;
*/

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int main( void ) {
    const uint64_t LUT = 0xAc607c59Bc12c483;

    char *mon[] = {
        "jan", "feb", "mar", "apr", "may", "jun",
        "JUL", "AUG", "SEP", "OCT", "NOV", "DEC",
        NULL
    };

    for( char **pm = mon; *pm; pm++ ) {
    //  char a = pm[0][0]; // irrelevant
        char b = pm[0][1];
        char c = pm[0][2];

        int bmngl  = b >> 2 & 0x7; // mangle the bits of 2nd character
        int cmngl  = c << 1;       // mangle the bits of 3rd character
        int LUTidx = bmngl ^ cmngl & 0xF; // combine and mask

        int rShift = 4 * LUTidx; // will right shift LUT 4*n bits

        int monOrd = (int)( LUT >> rShift ) & 0xF; // shift and mask

        printf("%s: hash = %2d ==> LU1 = %2d, LU2 = %2d, LU3 = %2d\n",
            pm[0],
            LUTidx,
            monOrd,
            // casting to int simulates return: int monthOrd( char *name );
            (int)( LUT >> 4 * ( ( b / 4 & 7 ) ^ ( c * 2 ) & 15 ) & 15 ),
            (int)( LUT>>4*(b/4&7^c*2&15)&15 ) // confident of precedence
        );
    }

    puts( "\nFalse positives:" );
    char *junk[] = { "COVID-19", "junk", "technical", "fopbar", NULL };

    for( char **pj = junk; *pj; pj++ ) {
        char b = pj[0][1];
        char c = pj[0][2];
        printf("%10s: LU = %2d\n", pj[0], (int)( LUT>>4*(b/4&7^c*2&15)&15 ) );
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
jan: hash = 12 ==> LU1 =  0, LU2 =  0, LU3 =  0
feb: hash =  5 ==> LU1 =  1, LU2 =  1, LU3 =  1
mar: hash =  4 ==> LU1 =  2, LU2 =  2, LU3 =  2
apr: hash =  0 ==> LU1 =  3, LU2 =  3, LU3 =  3
may: hash =  2 ==> LU1 =  4, LU2 =  4, LU3 =  4
jun: hash =  9 ==> LU1 =  5, LU2 =  5, LU3 =  5
JUL: hash = 13 ==> LU1 =  6, LU2 =  6, LU3 =  6
AUG: hash = 11 ==> LU1 =  7, LU2 =  7, LU3 =  7
SEP: hash =  1 ==> LU1 =  8, LU2 =  8, LU3 =  8
OCT: hash =  8 ==> LU1 =  9, LU2 =  9, LU3 =  9
NOV: hash = 15 ==> LU1 = 10, LU2 = 10, LU3 = 10
DEC: hash =  7 ==> LU1 = 11, LU2 = 11, LU3 = 11

False positives:
  COVID-19: LU = 10 // not "November" or any other month name
      junk: LU =  5 // not "June" or any other month name
 technical: LU = 11 // not "December" or any other month name
    fopbar: LU = 12 // outside of range 0-11. definitely not a month name!
```

**UPDATED Update:**
Inspired by the clarity of code in the recent answer by @chrqlie, there's this... It compiles to the same amount of assembler, but doesn't have the baggage of additional data. (Requiring a 64bit machine, it's probably not suitable for MCUs.) Again, the size of the LUT is only 8 bytes...

```
static int monthOrd( char *mn ) {
#define HASH(a,b,c) ((((b + b + c)&15) - ((b & 3) == 3))*4)
    static const uint64_t LUT
        = (uint64_t) 1 << HASH('j','a','n')
        | (uint64_t) 2 << HASH('f','e','b')
        | (uint64_t) 3 << HASH('m','a','r')
        | (uint64_t) 4 << HASH('a','p','r')
        | (uint64_t) 5 << HASH('m','a','y')
        | (uint64_t) 6 << HASH('j','u','n')
        | (uint64_t) 7 << HASH('j','u','l')
        | (uint64_t) 8 << HASH('a','u','g')
        | (uint64_t) 9 << HASH('s','e','p')
        | (uint64_t)10 << HASH('o','c','t')
        | (uint64_t)11 << HASH('n','o','v')
        | (uint64_t)12 << HASH('d','e','c')
        ;

    return -1 + (0xF & (int)(LUT >> HASH('x', mn[1], mn[2])));
#undef HASH
}
```

Further update: The first version of `monthOrd()` calculated a 4 bit hash and returned `0` for 4/16 cases where the passed string bore no resemblance to the name of a month. (It returned `1-12` for 12/16 cases that hashed to match the name of a particular month.) This was 'improved' in a later version, returning `0-11` to follow the convention of `struct tm`. Unfortunately, this meant the caller would have to use `strcmp()` to discern `"Jan(uary)"` (`0`) from the 4 wannabees (also `0`.) Not good!

The most recent version (just edited) still returns the desired `0-11` for the 12 hashed month names (including false positives, if those are a possibility). The edited version now returns `-1` for the 25% of the cases where the string could not possibly be the name of a month (ie. the string's hash value shows it to be a wannnabee.)

The caller need not invoke `strcmp()` when `monthOrd( str )` returns `-1`. Shaving cycles...

Comment: `return "DIE@CB@LJF@HAG@K"[ cp[1]/4&7 ^ cp[2]*2 &0xF ] &0xF;` did you try to pass peers review? What did they say?

Comment: @CostantinoGrana Thank you for the UV... There will have to be at least one "verification" that the unknown string matches a known string. Loops & branching aren't cheap. This "branchless" determination of the only potential match to verify the unknown shaves cycles. I first wrote something like this (simpler with a larger LUT) 40 years ago for a PDP11/34. It meant the job was completed and purged involving less wasteful swapping on that 1/2Mb of core system.

Comment: @0___________ No, no "review" except to test it functioned as desired... Admittedly arcane and "non-obvious" (ie: "illegible"), but one can't argue with success (as defined, "fulfills requirements".)

Comment: This method is useless as it gives result in the correct range for completely wrong input example: `monthOrd("Luty"));` is returning 7. So to check the if user has entered the correct month you need to use strcmp or different method anyway.

Comment: @0___________ You're missing the point. "Luty" is not the name of any month, but the hash is exactly the same as "July"... Since a single strcmp() shows "Luty" is not "July", the job is done. There's no need to make up to 11 more calls to strcmp() to check other possibilities... Even if the function returns 7, "Julie" is not "July"... With the hash, only one "verification" is needed; no more than that.

Comment: Congratulations. You've optimized the heck out of converting month names to integers. Yay. It's a cool hack and everything, but I'll bet that over the lifetime of this code, the amount of time it saves won't even come close to the amount of time you spent building it. If I ran across something like this during code review, I wouldn't let it pass. You might be able to explain it, but it's hardly clear and provably correct code. So, good on ya for the cool hack. I guess.

Comment: @JimMischel Not just a cool hack (developed after hours as a recreational foray into programmatic permutations), but three cool hacks to serve three small, unchanging lexicons. A feature of hashing is the risk of collisions, so results must be "cross checked"... Cross checking is up to the caller.

Comment: @JimMischel This might be more useful than it might seem at a glance. Standard C does for example offer you the possibility to get a compile-time time stamp of when your code was compiled, through the `__DATE__` constant. Which would be very useful on many occasions, if it wasn't using such a brain-damaged format: `"Jan 27 2023"` as a string literal. In several projects I've needed to place a time stamp into resource-constrained firmware, but the string literal was simply not helpful since it can't get used in calculations. So off I go to macro hell, to come back with some abomination... ->

Comment: In these situations a quick look-up in run-time wouldn't be a problem, since you are about to do some calculation based on the date anyway.

Comment: @Lundin Thank you for providing a justifiable "use case"... `:-)`

Comment: So, err, just to be clear, was this an original discovery by yourself, or is it some previously known trick? ("known" perhaps only in some niche circles that collect obscure optimizations like this, but anyway.)

Comment: @ilkkachu I "invented" `monthOrd()` to solve a real problem when core memory was really cores measured in Kb and cycle times measured in 10's of uS... It served a real purpose.. The others are recent _play_ to pass some time.

Comment: @Fe2O3, brilliant. I suppose in the days of core memory, I suppose it might have taken some manual fiddling...

Comment: @ilkkachu Thanks for the UV. :-) Back in the day, several thousand student records were periodically received from another institution, each having dates expressed as "Mar" or "Oct". We wanted them sortable by date (numeric). The "if/else strcmp()" translation burned countless cycles (on a UNIX system shared by up to 8 users) compounded by unproductive "swapping" to disk. This do-able optimisation meant the task completed "in the wink of an eye" and the system was liberated to perform other work. (Just to say, a 'gperf' solution would be faster, but much, much larger! :-)

Answer (score 4):

I've checked what happens with `gperf` passing it all months as "January", "Jan", "JANUARY", "JAN", "january", "jan", and so on.

```
struct months {
char *name;
int number;
};

#define TOTAL_KEYWORDS 69
#define MIN_WORD_LENGTH 3
#define MAX_WORD_LENGTH 9
#define MIN_HASH_VALUE 3
#define MAX_HASH_VALUE 218
/* maximum key range = 216, duplicates = 0 */

#ifdef __GNUC__
__inline
#else
#ifdef __cplusplus
inline
#endif
#endif
static unsigned int
hash (register const char *str, register size_t len)
{
  static unsigned char asso_values[] =
    {
      219, 219, 219, 219, 219, 219, 219, 219, 219, 219,
      219, 219, 219, 219, 219, 219, 219, 219, 219, 219,
      219, 219, 219, 219, 219, 219, 219, 219, 219, 219,
      219, 219, 219, 219, 219, 219, 219, 219, 219, 219,
      219, 219, 219, 219, 219, 219, 219, 219, 219, 219,
      219, 219, 219, 219, 219, 219, 219, 219, 219, 219,
      219, 219, 219, 219, 219,  10,  80,  75,  95,   5,
      125,  95, 219, 219,   5, 219,  95,  55,  45,  60,
       60, 219,  85,  95,  50,  90,  25, 219, 219,  12,
      219, 219, 219, 219, 219, 219, 219,   0,  40,  35,
       35,  35,  40,  25, 219, 219,   0, 219,  10,  50,
        0,  25,  15, 219,  15,  35,  30,  10,  25, 219,
      219,  25, 219, 219, 219, 219, 219, 219, 219, 219,
      219, 219, 219, 219, 219, 219, 219, 219, 219, 219,
      219, 219, 219, 219, 219, 219, 219, 219, 219, 219,
      219, 219, 219, 219, 219, 219, 219, 219, 219, 219,
      219, 219, 219, 219, 219, 219, 219, 219, 219, 219,
      219, 219, 219, 219, 219, 219, 219, 219, 219, 219,
      219, 219, 219, 219, 219, 219, 219, 219, 219, 219,
      219, 219, 219, 219, 219, 219, 219, 219, 219, 219,
      219, 219, 219, 219, 219, 219, 219, 219, 219, 219,
      219, 219, 219, 219, 219, 219, 219, 219, 219, 219,
      219, 219, 219, 219, 219, 219, 219, 219, 219, 219,
      219, 219, 219, 219, 219, 219, 219, 219, 219, 219,
      219, 219, 219, 219, 219, 219, 219, 219, 219, 219,
      219, 219, 219, 219, 219, 219
    };
  return len + asso_values[(unsigned char)str[2]] + asso_values[(unsigned char)str[1]] + asso_values[(unsigned char)str[0]];
}

struct months *
in_word_set (register const char *str, register size_t len)
{
  static struct months wordlist[] =
    {
      {""}, {""}, {""},
      {"jan",1},
      {""}, {""}, {""},
      {"january",1},
      {"Jan",1},
      {""}, {""}, {""},
      {"January",1},
      {"jun",6},
      {"june",6},
      {""}, {""}, {""},
      {"Jun",6},
      {"June",6},
      {""}, {""}, {""},
      {"jul",7},
      {"july",7},
      {""}, {""}, {""},
      {"Jul",7},
      {"July",7},
      {""}, {""}, {""},
      {"apr",4},
      {""},
      {"april",4},
      {""}, {""},
      {"aug",8},
      {""}, {""},
      {"august",8},
      {""},
      {"Apr",4},
      {""},
      {"April",4},
      {""}, {""},
      {"Aug",8},
      {""}, {""},
      {"August",8},
      {""},
      {"nov",11},
      {""}, {""}, {""}, {""},
      {"november",11},
      {""}, {""}, {""}, {""},
      {"JAN",1},
      {""}, {""}, {""},
      {"JANUARY",1},
      {"mar",3},
      {""},
      {"march",3},
      {""}, {""},
      {"Mar",3},
      {""},
      {"March",3},
      {""}, {""},
      {"may",5},
      {""},
      {"MAY",5},
      {""}, {""},
      {"May",5},
      {""}, {""}, {""}, {""},
      {"sep",9},
      {""}, {""}, {""}, {""},
      {"oct",10},
      {"september",9},
      {""}, {""},
      {"october",10},
      {"Nov",11},
      {""}, {""}, {""}, {""},
      {"November",11},
      {""}, {""}, {""}, {""},
      {"dec",12},
      {""}, {""}, {""}, {""},
      {"december",12},
      {""}, {""}, {""}, {""},
      {"feb",2},
      {""}, {""}, {""}, {""},
      {"february",2},
      {""}, {""}, {""}, {""},
      {"Oct",10},
      {""}, {""}, {""},
      {"October",10},
      {"NOV",11},
      {""}, {""}, {""}, {""},
      {"NOVEMBER",11},
      {""}, {""}, {""}, {""},
      {"JUN",6},
      {"JUNE",6},
      {""}, {""}, {""},
      {"Sep",9},
      {""}, {""}, {""}, {""},
      {"MAR",3},
      {"September",9},
      {"MARCH",3},
      {""}, {""},
      {"APR",4},
      {""},
      {"APRIL",4},
      {""}, {""},
      {"SEP",9},
      {""}, {""}, {""}, {""},
      {"Dec",12},
      {"SEPTEMBER",9},
      {""}, {""}, {""},
      {"December",12},
      {""}, {""}, {""}, {""},
      {"DEC",12},
      {""}, {""}, {""}, {""},
      {"DECEMBER",12},
      {""}, {""}, {""}, {""},
      {"OCT",10},
      {""}, {""}, {""},
      {"OCTOBER",10},
      {"JUL",7},
      {"JULY",7},
      {""}, {""}, {""},
      {"AUG",8},
      {""}, {""},
      {"AUGUST",8},
      {""},
      {"Feb",2},
      {""}, {""}, {""}, {""},
      {"February",2},
      {""}, {""}, {""}, {""},
      {"FEB",2},
      {""}, {""}, {""}, {""},
      {"FEBRUARY",2}
    };

  if (len <= MAX_WORD_LENGTH && len >= MIN_WORD_LENGTH)
    {
      register unsigned int key = hash (str, len);

      if (key <= MAX_HASH_VALUE)
        {
          register const char *s = wordlist[key].name;

          if (*str == *s && !strcmp (str + 1, s + 1))
            return &wordlist[key];
        }
    }
  return 0;
}
```

I guess this is pretty fast and requires only one `strcmp` per string. This is exactly what is used in GCC for keyword checking.

A very nice introduction to `gperf` is available [here](https://www.dre.vanderbilt.edu/%7Eschmidt/PDF/gperf.pdf).

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple solution that should be more efficient and will check for proper spelling:

```
#include <string.h>

int get_month_number(const char *s) {
    if (s && s[0] && s[1]) {
        switch (s[2]) {
          case 'n': return !strcmp(s, "Jan") || !strcmp(s, "January")   ? 1 :
                           !strcmp(s, "Jun") || !strcmp(s, "June")      ? 6 : 0;
          case 'b': return !strcmp(s, "Feb") || !strcmp(s, "February")  ? 2 : 0;
          case 'r': return !strcmp(s, "Mar") || !strcmp(s, "March")     ? 3 :
                           !strcmp(s, "Apr") || !strcmp(s, "April")     ? 4 : 0;
          case 'y': return !strcmp(s, "May")                            ? 5 : 0;
          case 'l': return !strcmp(s, "Jul") || !strcmp(s, "July")      ? 7 : 0;
          case 'g': return !strcmp(s, "Aug") || !strcmp(s, "August")    ? 8 : 0;
          case 'p': return !strcmp(s, "Sep") || !strcmp(s, "September") ? 9 : 0;
          case 't': return !strcmp(s, "Oct") || !strcmp(s, "October")   ? 10 : 0;
          case 'v': return !strcmp(s, "Nov") || !strcmp(s, "November")  ? 11 : 0;
          case 'c': return !strcmp(s, "Dec") || !strcmp(s, "December")  ? 12 : 0;

        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

If you can assume that `s` points to a string of at least 3 characters that represents an English month name in ASCII, abbreviated or not, using any case combination, you can simplify the above code while keeping it readable:

```
// return the month number 0..11 assuming argument is correct.
int get_month_number(const char *s) {
#define HASH(a,b,c)  ((((b) | 0x20) == 'a') + ((c) & 0x1f))
    switch (HASH(s[0],s[1],s[2])) {
      default:
      case HASH('J','a','n'): return 0;
      case HASH('F','e','b'): return 1;
      case HASH('M','a','r'): return 2;
      case HASH('A','p','r'): return 3;
      case HASH('M','a','y'): return 4;
      case HASH('J','u','n'): return 5;
      case HASH('J','u','l'): return 6;
      case HASH('A','u','g'): return 7;
      case HASH('S','e','p'): return 8;
      case HASH('O','c','t'): return 9;
      case HASH('N','o','v'): return 10;
      case HASH('D','e','c'): return 11;
    }
#undef HASH
}
```

And here is an alternative with a look up table instead of a `switch` statement:

```
// return the month number 0..11 assuming argument is correct.
int get_month_number(const char *s) {
#define HASH(a,b,c)  ((((b) | 0x20) == 'a') + ((c) & 0x1f))
    static const unsigned char month_num[33] = {
        [ HASH('J','a','n') ] = 0,
        [ HASH('F','e','b') ] = 1,
        [ HASH('M','a','r') ] = 2,
        [ HASH('A','p','r') ] = 3,
        [ HASH('M','a','y') ] = 4,
        [ HASH('J','u','n') ] = 5,
        [ HASH('J','u','l') ] = 6,
        [ HASH('A','u','g') ] = 7,
        [ HASH('S','e','p') ] = 8,
        [ HASH('O','c','t') ] = 9,
        [ HASH('N','o','v') ] = 10,
        [ HASH('D','e','c') ] = 11,
    };
    return month_num[HASH(s[0],s[1],s[2])];
#undef HASH
}
```

As can be seen on [Godbolt's Compiler Explore](https://godbolt.org/z/ajWdG8e54)r, both functions generate branchless code with **gcc** and **clang**. The `switch` statement also detects hash collisions for free.  Both could use your hash function:

```
#define HASH(a,b,c)  ((b)/4&7 ^ (c)*2&0xF)
```

Comment: Requires caller to isolate candidate as as a null terminated string. One, possibly two, and as many as three calls to `strcmp()` to determine `"June"`. Wanted to eliminate or reduce calls to `strcmp()`! Does this continue work when the source changes from mixed case to all uppercase? eg "JAN"? And, `stricmp()` will be more expensive than `strcmp()`... (Note: my updated answer changes from `1-12` and `0` to `struct tm` convention of `0-11` using `12` for NAM (ie: definitely not the name of a month! not even close!).)

Comment: My answer leaves determination of "proper spelling" to the caller. If the source of the candidate string is reliable (like the 3 letter month name within `__DATE__` in a C program), there's no need to check spelling. Just want the month region of `25 DEC 2023` to be converted to `11` (where Jan == 0)...

Comment: Memory is cheap and abundant (except on embedded systems where it's a significant consideration.) That's why the gperf idea isn't a good general solution. With its 23 string literals, _this_ solution might tax the intended platform's limited resources.

Comment: @Fe2O3: Your solutions are compact, but impossible to validate without exhaustive analysis.  Transposing your approach to other languages is even harder.  I amended my answer with alternative versions that combine compactness of code and data with a method that is both readable and easy to validate.  I too remember *those days* where I would spent hours seeking ways to shave off some CPU cycles and a few memory bytes... Thanks for reviving such good memories :)

Comment: It **is** fun, isn't it? `:-)`... Both your added solutions are **FAR** more obvious (than mine) to the reader and more maintainable! Good job! The long-ago version I wrote also used a sparse array like yours, but I hadn't seen the clearer/clever hashing function you've used here. Nice!