# Do...while loop only working for one condition in C

Tags: c

Can somebody explain why the do...while loop is repeating itself in for b, B, c, or C but not if you put a or A? This is a subpart of the code I am writing up. I want to limit the number of input to only a, b, or c so that any other input just repeats itself until it gets one of the correct letters.

```
do{
        printf("Which package would you like to select? A, B, or C ");
        scanf(" %c", &package_choice);
}while(toupper((unsigned char)package_choice) != 'A' && 'B' && 'C');
```

I have changed the && to || but it repeats itself over and over no matter the input. I went through and did the (unsigned char)package_choice) != to each letter to see if that changed anything but I got the same result. I'm still learning C in school and am having a hard time understanding some of the basic formats that go along with C. Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line is not doing what you think it does:

```
while(toupper((unsigned char)package_choice) != 'A' && 'B' && 'C');
```

... what the above actually does is logically equivalent to this:

```
while(toupper((unsigned char)package_choice) != 'A' && ('B' != 0) && ('C' != 0));
```

... and since 'B' (aka ASCII value 66) and 'C' (aka ASCII value 67) are always not equal to zero, those parts of the expression will always trivially evaluate to true and therefore have no effect on the behavior of the test.

Rewritten to properly express the logic you intended, the expression should look like this:

```
while(toupper((unsigned char)package_choice) != 'A' 
   && toupper((unsigned char)package_choice) != 'B' 
   && toupper((unsigned char)package_choice) != 'C');
```

Comment: I understand roughly half of what you said haha, what exactly is the ASCII value stuff? That is the first time I have seen it before.

Outside of that part I see what you're saying. I'll plug it into the code and try again.

Comment: @jtward17 since computers only understand numbers (not letters), we need a convention by which each letter corresponds to a particular well-known number so that the computer can store its value.  The most common convention (for English letters, anyway) is the ASCII convention, as shown in the charts on this page:  https://www.rapidtables.com/code/text/ascii-table.html

Comment: I appreciate the explanation. I had an idea about computers using numbers over letters but not to the extent that you showed me. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 3):

C doesn't work that way.

The expression `toupper((unsigned char)package_choice) != 'A' && 'B' && 'C'`
might look like a near-English-language expression to you, but it has a vastly different meaning to a C compiler.

To check that a value is NOT one of several different values, first compute the value you want to compare:

```
char t = toupper((unsigned char)package_choice);
```

Then check that value against each option:

```
while( (t != 'A') && (t != 'B') && (t != 'C') );
```

Total expression:

```
char t;
do{
        printf("Which package would you like to select? A, B, or C ");
        scanf(" %c", &package_choice);
        t = toupper((unsigned char)package_choice);
} while( (t != 'A') && (t != 'B') && (t != 'C') );
```

(Also, you should check the return value of `scanf` to find out if it successfully got input at all!)

Comment: That's a different way of going about it. I haven't seen that before. Is that essentially just condensing the conditions down in the while() code?

Answer (score 0):

Others have already pointed out how `&&` (and `||`) are logical operators used to join the results of two conditionals. Unfortunately, your code made improper use of those.

For a limited set of valid single character inputs, there is also the option to use one of C's standard "string library functions". In this case `strchr()`.

```
#include <string.h>
//...
do {
    // stuff
} while( !strchr( "ABCabc", package_choice ) );
```

If the character is NOT found in the supplied string of valid choice, a null pointer is returned, and the **not** condition evaluates `true`, so the loop is repeated.

Make yourself familiar with C's string functions. They're used everywhere.

You could use a similar version in the other `do/while()` of your program.

```
do {
    // stuff
} while( !strchr( "Yy", package_verify ) );
```

Comment: I had never seen that used before, or at least it hasn't been taught in the class I'm in. I appreciate the insight!

Comment: @jtward17 The intrigue of C (and coding in general) is that there are usually many different solutions... Completely unrelated, have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/75242342/17592432 Yeah, I'm kinda proud o' that... :-)